# CDATA block displays as a commented out in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, cdata

I'm trying to render some html inside `<![CDATA[ ]]` block passed to dangerouslySetInnerHTML in ReactJS and this content renders as a commented out. E.g. I get `<!--[CDATA[Where is my text?]]-->` instead of `[CDATA[Where is my text?]]` in the DOM.

```js
const HTML_OK = '<pre>My text looks good</pre>'
const HTML_CDATA = '<pre><![CDATA[Where is my text?]]></pre>'

class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.html }} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
 <div>
    <Hello html={HTML_OK} />
    <Hello html={HTML_CDATA} />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

How can I get `<![CDATA[ ]]` displays ok in my React application?

Comment: It seems that you cannot display CDATA if you serve your page as text/html. This topic may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746803/is-it-possible-to-use-cdata-inside-pre-tag